# How to subtract values from a list with values from the same list?

Tags: python, list, subtraction

I have the following list:

```
91747, 280820, 334845, 531380, 585594, 657296, 711726, ...
```

I want to subtract the second value with the first value, the third with the second, and so on. The results I want to transfer into a new list.

The output should be

```
189073, 54025, ...
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `[j - i for i, j in itertools.pairwise(lst)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this :

```
# the source list
mylist = [91747, 280820, 334845, 531380, 585594, 657296, 711726]

# the new output list using list comprehension
result = [x - y for x, y in zip(mylist[1:], mylist[:len(mylist)-1])]

# printing the result
print(result)
```

Output :

```
[189073, 54025, 196535, 54214, 71702, 54430]
```